# Is it true that an $n^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 5 \Rightarrow 5 \vert n$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

I want to use this as a lemma in a different proof, but I'm not sure if it holds. I would suspect it does, since: $n^2 \mod 5$ is in $\{0, 1, 4\}$ for all integers $n$, and only $0$ puts $0$ in this set, but I don't think this is enough to prove it. Can this be proved, or am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah.  It's true.  Brut force tells you $n\equiv 0,\pm 1,\pm 2 \mod 5$ and $n^2\ equiv 0, 1 ,4\mod 5$.

Comment: That _is_  to prove it.

Comment: The method you used works for best for the general case; note that for $p$ prime, $p\mid n^2\Rightarrow p\mid n$. One way to prove this is to show that $p\mid ab, a,b\in Z\Rightarrow p\mid a\ OR\ p\mid b$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof verification: If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $\gcd(a^2,b^2)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2484038/proof-verification-if-gcda-b-1-then-gcda2-b2-1)

Comment: Suppose on contrary that $\gcd(a,5)=1$, which implies that $5 \mid \gcd(a^2,5) \mid \gcd(a^2,25)=1$; which is an obvious contradiction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p \implies p | n$ holds for all prime $p$ (so, yes, it does hold for your case of $p=5$).

It does not necessarily hold for composite $p$, e.g. consider $n^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ and see if it's necessarily true that $4 | n$?

Comment: Yes, $2$ puts another $0$ in the set for $\bmod 4$ so it makes sense that it doesn't hold for that. Can you prove that it actually holds for all primes $p$ though?

Comment: Why not try it yourself as a simple exercise? Consider the prime factorisation of a square number.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak, I figured out the proof. You were right -- it was trivial since $p$ is prime. Thanks!

Comment: @user2059300 Great! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are only 5 equivalence classes.  Brute force will verify $n\equiv 0 \mod 5\iff n^2\equiv 0\mod 5$.

This is overkill, but if $p $ is prime, then of the $p $ equivalence classes $0 \mod p $ is the only divisor of zero[1] and so $n \times m\equiv 0$ only if either $n $ or $m \equiv 0 \mod p $.  Therefore $n^k\equiv 0\iff n\equiv 0\mod p $.

So,yes, you can state that.

[1] $n \times m\equiv 0 \implies n \times m=kp\implies p|n \times m $ but as $p $ is prime either $p|n $ or $p|m $, i.e. either $n $ or $m \equiv 0 \mod p$.

Answer (score 0):

Simple proof: by contrapositive.

Harder proof but still valid: using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic

Forst is useful, second is kinda fun to work with

Answer (score 0):

Euclid's Lemma:

If $p$, prime, divides $ab$, then $p|a$ or $p|b.$

Hence: $p|n^2$ $ \rightarrow$  $p|n.$

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma