# Proof verification: If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $\gcd(a^2,b^2)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Proof(by contraposition): *the tagged duplicate is trying to use bezout's identity while this post is trying not to*

Suppose $\gcd(a^2,b^2)>1$ then $a^2$ & $b^2$ have a common factor greater than 1. W.L.O.G., it could be that $a\mid b$ or $a=b^n$ for some $n\in \Bbb{Z}$ or $a=b^{\frac{m}{k}}$ for some $k,m\in \Bbb{Z}$.

Case 1: $a|b$ iff $|a|\leq |b|$. Assuming that $a\neq 1$ and $b\neq 1$, then $gcd(a,b)\neq 1$.

Case 2: $a=b^n$ iff $b=\sqrt[n]{a}$, then $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,\sqrt[n]{a})=\sqrt[n]{a} \neq 1$ assuming $a\neq 1$.

Case 3: $a=b^{\frac nk}$ iff $b=\sqrt[k]{a^n}$, then $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,\sqrt[k]{a^n}) \neq \sqrt[k]{a^n} \neq 1$ assuming $a \neq 1$.

Thus, for all cases, if $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $\gcd(a^2,b^2)=1$. QED

I think what I wrote is correct, but I am not that confident it is.

Comment: That is not the only case.  For example, $\gcd(6^2,10^2) \neq1$ but you can't write $6=10^{m/k}$

Comment: How could a "proof verification" question be a duplicate? Does the other OP use the same argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof should be simpler. Note that if a prime $p$ divides $a^2$ and $b^2$ then $p$ divides $a$ and $b$ (use [Prove that if $p$ is a prime, $a$ is an integer, and $p$ divides $a^2$, then $p$ divides $a$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1921953/prove-that-if-p-is-a-prime-a-is-an-integer-and-p-divides-a2-then-p)).

Comment: Suppose $gcd(a^2,b^2)=d$ then $d|a^2$ and $d|b^2$. If $d$ is composite then there exist a prime $p$ that divides $d$ which implies $p|a^2$ and $p|b^2$. By Euclid's Lemma, if $p|a^2$ then $p|a$ or $p|a$ and same thing goes why $p|b$. Thus, $p|a$ and $p|b$. Thus, by contraposition, the above claim is true. QED...?

Comment: Correct. Just say if $d>1$ then  there is a prime $p$ which divides $d$.